# having trouble iterating through a loop and drawing boxes

Tags: python, arrays, pygame, tetris

I'm trying to implement Tetris in Pygame. I wanted to test out an algorithm involving arrays that would in theory draw boxes in a grid. Instead, whenever I run the code, the window pops up and only one square is drawn in the corner of the window.

So I started by making a 2d array -- 20 arrays each with 10 zeros, each zero representing a cell in the game board. Then i used a for loop to iterate through each cell, theoretically drawing a square for each zero in the array. I'm still at the stage where I'm trying to iterate through each zero in a sub-array.

game.py:

```
    import pygame

    board_arr = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

    def iterate_board(screen, rect):
        for i in board_arr:
            for j in i:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, "red", rect)
                rect.x += rect.width
```

and then I call the "iterate_board" function inside of main.py.

The problem with this is that only one square seems to get drawn.

```
    import pygame
    import game

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
    #screen = game.screen
    bg_hue = "black"
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    squ = pygame.Rect(0, 10, 20, 20)

    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            
        screen.fill(bg_hue)

        game.iterate_board(screen,squ)

        pygame.display.update()
     
        clock.tick(60)

    pygame.quit()
```

EDIT: By request, here's the rest of the code. I tweaked it a little, but it's still generally the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You paint all the blocks in one row because you never change `rect.y`. Then, in the next run of the `while` loop, you overwrite everything with `screen.fill(bg_hue)` and try to paint again, but the position of `rect.x` is now on the right outside the window area. This means that you actually paint, but no one can see it anymore.

I added the change to the y-position, the reset of the x-position for a new row, and made sure to not overwrite the initial square.

I also added a function to alter random blocks of the board, so that you can see that it works.

```
import random
import pygame

the_board = [[0 for x in range(10)] for y in range(20)]


def change_random_block(board):
    x = random.randrange(len(board))
    y = random.randrange(len(board[x]))
    board[x][y] = 1 - board[x][y]


def iterate_board(screen, initial_rect, board):
    rect = initial_rect.copy()
    for row in board:
        for block in row:
            if block == 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, "red", rect)
            rect.x += rect.width
        rect.x = initial_rect.x
        rect.y += rect.height


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
bg_hue = "black"
run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
square = pygame.Rect(0, 10, 20, 20)

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    screen.fill(bg_hue)
    iterate_board(screen, square, the_board)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
    change_random_block(the_board)

pygame.quit()
```

---

A small hint: If you use `rect.x += rect.width + 1` and `rect.y += rect.height + 1` you can see the grid.